# Change logging format in a class instance

Tags: python, django

This is a Python question but a Django-specific solution is acceptable.

For a class I'm writing I would like to prefix log output on a per-instance basis. I do not want to interfere with the  logging destinations that were set up. These are the solutions I can think of:

1. create a new logger as a sub-logger of the module, reconfigure the parent handlers with different formatters: `mylog.info("foo") => prefixfoo`
2. create a wrapper log class with the info(), warn() etc methods, each adding the prefix before calling the wrapped logger: `mylog.info("foo")`
3. store the prefix in the instance and manually add: `log.info(self.p+"foo")`
4. create a prefix-adding function that I manually wrap all log calls with: `log.info(p("foo"))`

Obviously I prefer solution 1 but I don't know how to do that.

What is the best solution? I'm a newbie Python programmer so I'm probably trying to solve the wrong problem :-)

Comment: Have you looked at [logbook](http://pythonhosted.org//Logbook/quickstart.html#configuring-the-logging-format)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid no, but it seems to replace `logging`, while I want to integrate with code that already uses `logging`...